# Write a function named isSuper that returns 1 if its array argument is a isSuper array, otherwise it returns 0

Tags: java, array

An Super array is defined to be an array in which each element is greater than sum of all elements before that.
 
For example:

- `{2, 3, 6, 13}` is a Super array. (`2 < 3`, `2+3 < 6`, `2 + 3 + 6 < 13`)
- `{2, 3, 5, 11}` is a NOT a Super array. `2 + 3 < 5` is false.

I wrote following code to find the array is Super Array or not .

```
public class SuperArray {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
         System.out.println("The result is: " + isSupper(new int[] {2, 3, 6, 13}));
         System.out.println("The result is: " + isSupper(new int[] {2, 3, 5, 11}));
    }
    public static int isSupper(int[] a){
        int result = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int nextValue = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            nextValue = a[i];   
            if(nextValue > sum) {   
                result = 1;
            } else {
                result = 0;
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("sum is: " + sum);
            System.out.println("next Value is: " + nextValue);
            sum += a[i];       
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Is this a good way to find Super array? First a assign sum = 0 and check that sum to first number of an array and so on.

Comment: related:[PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69661/80010)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Method name and return types

```
public static int isSupper(int[] a)
```

As mentioned in [@200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/117179/24141)'s answer, a method that begins with `is`, by Java convention, is (pun unintended) usually expected to return a `boolean`. Looking at this method, it should tell me if the argument is a <s>set of supper times</s> 'super array' or not.

#### Edge cases

Your implementation also implicitly *rejects* negative values, as you start with `sum = 0` as the comparison. Is `{ -100, 0, 100 }` really not a 'super array'?

How about when we are adding very large numbers then?

```
System.out.println(isSupper(new int[] {Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0 }));

// output
sum is: 0
next Value is: 2147483646
sum is: 2147483646
next Value is: 2147483647
sum is: -3
next Value is: 0
1
```

Answer (score 7):

It's easier to use the enhanced for loop like this:

```
    for(int value : a) {
        if(value <= sum) 
            return 0;
        sum += value;       
    }
    return 1;
```

This also clears up some unnecessary lines like checking if the function should break and return. When you return a value, it immediately leaves the function. Therefore, you don't need to break then return. If all value pass the for loop, then it will return 1.

Also, you might want to return `boolean` instead of `int` in your method because it's just true or false.

Answer (score 7):

Watch your spelling: you spelled "super" correctly in the class name, but not the function name.

A function that produces a yes/no response is called a *predicate*, and it should return a `boolean` rather than an `int`.  (If the exercise requires an `int` return value, then I would consider it a poorly written exercise.)

Consider changing the function signature to `public static boolean isSuper(int... a)`.  Then you have the option to call the function using either

```
isSuper(2, 3, 6, 13)
```

or

```
isSuper(new int[] { 2, 3, 6, 13 })
```

Note that the class has an [implicit `SuperArray()` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9).  While it is harmless, I recommend suppressing it by defining

```
public class SuperArray {
    // Suppress the default constructor
    private SuperArray() {}

    public static boolean isSuper(int... a) {
        /* Insert what @TheProgrammerG said.  It's good advice. */
    }
}
```